# AlpineJS with CSP Build in a Chrome Extension Setting with Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, alpine.js

Following the instructions at https://alpinejs.dev/advanced/csp to build the CSP library and include it in a simple settings extension, the alpine data is executed but the click event never is executed nor is the text ever displayed.  No CSP errors are thrown.  Is there an issue with Alpine as it seems to not update the DOM.

settings.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Settings</title>
    <script src="alpine.js" defer></script>  <!-- cdn build from csp -->
    
</head>
<body>
      <div x-data="counter">
        <button @click="increment">Increment</button>

        <span x-text="count"></span>
    </div>
    
    <script src="settings.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

settings.js:

```
// this gets executed but the increment never does

Alpine.data('counter', () => ({
    count: 1,

    increment() {
        console.log('clicked');
        this.count++;
    }
}))
```

[image]

Comment: This was in the extension settings and I was looking at the correct console but, there was no csp errors.  It calls the Alpine.data methods but tthe page never updates.  I put a screenshot of the console.  If I try with the non csp build, it will throw the error.

Comment: Additionally, the settings page when run standalone doesn't work with the CSP build either.  The build is either broken, the docs aren't correct, or I'm missing something. :(